# JavaScript filter not working properly in my NUXT app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an array of objects that is gotten from an API, and I would like to filter out one of them based on the `_id` field. the problem is instead of filtering out the one that has the same `_id` it filters out everything instead.

Below is my code -- I also console.log each step so we can see what is happenning

in my NUXTJS method

```
        removeSingleImage(imageObjId) {
            this.$axios.delete(`/photo/${imageObjId}`)
            .then(result => {
                const olduploaded = this.uploaded
                console.log(olduploaded);
                const newUploaded = olduploaded.filter((item) => {
                    console.log("item._id", item._id);
                    console.log("imageObjId", imageObjId);
                    item._id !== imageObjId
                })
                this.uploaded = newUploaded
                console.log(newUploaded);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            })
        }
```

when this code `console.log(olduploaded);` runs, in the console I get the expected array as shown below

```
[
                {
                    "_id":"60de4a29e2c2850015c4dd78",
                    "location":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuIbd-D80_YPHKNJnLFuO2bHqk5NfNIna7ZQ&usqp=CAU",
                    "owner":"60dce43551e7df0015bd0b65",
                    "place":"60de48e3e2c2850015c4dd75",
                    "createdAt":"2021-07-01T23:05:13.264Z",
                    "updatedAt":"2021-07-01T23:05:13.264Z",
                    "__v":0},
                {
                    "_id":"60e3ad33804ed4001542ad7b",
                    "location":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472224371017-08207f84aaae?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
                    "owner":"60dce43551e7df0015bd0b65",
                    "place":"60de48e3e2c2850015c4dd75",
                    "createdAt":"2021-07-06T01:09:07.716Z",
                    "updatedAt":"2021-07-06T01:09:07.716Z",
                    "__v":0},
                {
                    "_id":"60faa55763da2f0015c19941","key":"photos/QtIQk0WanlWsaeB8w6agYSaHKnUuUb.webp",
                    "location":"https://lookaam.s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/photos/QtIQk0WanlWsaeB8w6agYSaHKnUuUb.webp",
                    "owner":"60dce43551e7df0015bd0b65",
                    "place":"60de48e3e2c2850015c4dd75",
                    "createdAt":"2021-07-23T11:17:43.359Z",
                    "updatedAt":"2021-07-23T11:17:43.359Z",
                    "__v":0},
                {
                    "_id":"60faa55863da2f0015c19942","key":"photos/MnacW4UFUWa0kyVjOX5cPBZxYBGLCs.webp",
                    "location":"https://lookaam.s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/photos/MnacW4UFUWa0kyVjOX5cPBZxYBGLCs.webp",
                    "owner":"60dce43551e7df0015bd0b65",
                    "place":"60de48e3e2c2850015c4dd75",
                    "createdAt":"2021-07-23T11:17:44.005Z",
                    "updatedAt":"2021-07-23T11:17:44.005Z",
                    "__v":0}
]
```

when i `console.log("item._id", item._id);` and `console.log("imageObjId", imageObjId);` for each item, i get

```
item._id 60de4a29e2c2850015c4dd78
imageObjId 60faa55863da2f0015c19942
item._id 60e3ad33804ed4001542ad7b
imageObjId 60faa55863da2f0015c19942
item._id 60faa55763da2f0015c19941
imageObjId 60faa55863da2f0015c19942
item._id 60faa55863da2f0015c19942
imageObjId 60faa55863da2f0015c19942
```

and as we can see the last `item._id` and `imageObjId` are the same and should be filtered out, but what I get instead when I filter them out and run `console.log(newUploaded)` is an empty array

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `return` inside the filter callback :

```
            const newUploaded = olduploaded.filter((item) => {
                console.log("item._id", item._id);
                console.log("imageObjId", imageObjId);
                return item._id !== imageObjId
                //
            })
```